ACF Tab Field: All fields after TAB fields are being added as a tab where I want only three fields as tab
I am using Advanced Custom Fields and version is 6.3.5. I have just started using ACF. I have used TAB field and I want only next three fields to be under tab, but its showing all fields subsequent fields as tab
Is there any way to exclude the fields from tab?
Regards,
Amit
